# How can you create a function that will have a specific definite integral over an integer domain that someone can choose?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I was wondering how and if there was a possible to create a function that will have a specific definite integral over an integer domain that someone can choose.

For example, lets say I want the result to be 0.4561234144 or 0.123456789, I want to know if it is possible to create a function lets say x^4 + x^3 + 42 is integrated between 0 to 5 the result would be one of the ones listed above.

If there was an algorithm or some sort of method that I could use would be great. I am not sure if this is possible but it would be interesting to know if that is possible. The thing that makes it hard is the integer domain for the integral as you can just create a random function and define the lower bound and then just solve it for the upper bound with the required solution

Thanks

Comment: To clarify: given $[a, b]$ and $A$, you want to find a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $\int_a^b p(x) \, dx = A$?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the polynomial $p$? The degree? Other things? Otherwise, this is trivial: just choose $p$ to be the constant function $A/(b-a)$.

Comment: I mean I used a polynomial but any function of any kind would be good. I mean I am just curious about how you would go about it with any function. Maybe its easier to start with polynomial?

Comment: @SammyBlack yeah the aim is to not actually have A in the function yeah because it is pretty trival otherwise. maybe degree greater than 2 and would integer coefficient work? Might need to be a trig and polynomial equation for that with all integer coefficients

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "integer domain." Are you requiring that the polynomial have integer coefficients and/or that the bounds are integers?

Comment: @Bonnaduck integers for both

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. I think what you are asking is whether there exists an integrable function $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, such that for any $r \in \Bbb{R}$, there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
\int_a^bf(x)dx = r
$$
No such function can exist, since the integrals on the left-hand side of the above equation range over the countably many pairs $(a, b)$, but there are uncountably many $r \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I believe what they mean is, for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$, how we can find an "appropriately nontrivial" (in this respect the question is not clear) integrable function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $$\int_a^b f(x)dx = r$$

Comment: @William: you might be right. The OP needs to clarify the question: on your (very likely correct reading), it is either trivial or involves some unspecified constraint on the solutions $f$.

Comment: Yes I did mean an appropriately nontrivial solution. There is so many ways to go with this and I am overwhelmed by it